# SonarLint - Invalid binding message in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarlint

I have installed the intellij/sonarlint plug in, and connected it to the sonarcloud successfully and selected a project. but i get the following error in intellij Event log:

1:04 PM SonarLint - Invalid binding
                Project bound to an invalid remote project

Can someone help? Thank you - Sheida

Answer (score 4):

The following way always resolved this problem for me:

- Open up your Sonarlint Project Configuration
- Click on "configure the connection..."
- Click on "Update binding"

Simple as it is it seems to just ask for verification of the known projects and their configuration settings.

Comment: how long does it late

Comment: It usually doesn‘t take longer than a few seconds. If it does, then it should either run into a timeout or other error. May check the log for that.