# SonarLint - Failed to update the following projects

Tags: sonarqube, intellij-plugin, sonarlint

This is similar to thread ["SonarLint - Invalid binding message in intellij"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866699/sonarlint-invalid-binding-message-in-intellij).

However, following the solution leads to another problem, which is stated in the title, or from below with following full message:

```
Failed to update the following projects: Please check if the server bindings are updated and the module key is correct: [module_name]
```

By the way, module name is correct because it is selected from the "Project" dropdown values, which are retrieved remotely.

Any clue(s)?

**EDIT:**
Right before the failure, log states that there is `GET 401` due to configuration of SiteMinder agent along with NTLM, or simply due to unsuccessful credential redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my own question, this may happen if there is proxy issues. I was able to see `Get 401` in the logs during the binding.

Here's the conversation I had with SonarQube team: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarlint-failed-to-update-the-following-projects/38471

Furthermore, if you experience this within the Corporate/Enterprise, reach out to DevOps team to acquire different endpoint. Enterprise configuration usually involves two endpoints:

- Endpoint for SSO
- Endpoint that handles/redirects API call

For SonarQube plugin to appropriately handle this, it will require endpoint that handles API.